# Опционно или опционально?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

Как правильно говорить: опционно или опционально. Возможно ли применение термина, например, в написании  кулинарных рецептов? К примеру: опционно - красный перец.

Answer (score 1):

По общеязыковой норме - только опционно. Но не в этом значении, самое близкое - из профессионального торгового слэнга, там это означает "за отдельную плату".
Поэтому либо пишите то, что вам ближе, и оговариваетесь, что это слэнг, либо пишете по-русски: по желанию, по вкусу и т.д.

Comment: Конечно же, по желанию, по вкусу - гораздо лучше. Скоро без словаря не прочтешь. Вот недавно, открыла Анну Борисову (то бишь Бориса Акунина). На первых же страницах - генерация, растаманы, джойнт, тендерные установки, гандикап... Лезть в словарь, чтобы убедиться, что я правильно поняла автора, не захотелось. Не то чтобы я этих слов не знаю (хотя джойнт и растаман - действительно не знаю), но хотелось читать, не спотыкаясь взглядом и мыслью. Отложила. Наверное, так же поступают дети, открывая классику: Непонятно. Не читаю.

Comment: Я бы ответил, что правильно - опционально. Но это первый взгляд. Оказывается, все не так просто. Если подумать, то слово "опционно", по крайней мере для меня, как будто происходит из банковской сферы =) Фондовые биржи и пр. С другой стороны, просто так путаница не могла возникнуть. И, я думаю, что она возникла из-за похожего английского слова optional - необязательный. Если мы его просто транскрибируем и добавим вполне русское окончание, то получим слово "опциональный". Ну, а "опционально" - это наречие от него же.

Comment: Соответственно, частота этих "неправильных" слов в технической лит-ре должна быть выше, чем в каких-либо других текстах. А это легко проверить.

Comment: Боюсь, у option, optional в английском главное значение сейчас не "необязательный", а "альтернативный". Связано с применением всяческих компьютерных программ, где "опциями" называются всяческие пункты меню, из которых обычно надо выбрать одну. Даже в тех случаях, когда надо просто "поставить галочку", фактически имеет место выбор из двух возможностей, отсутствие галочки означает не отсутствие какой-то возможности, а просто выбор другого режима. 
В русском языке подобное значение у "опция" есть только в программистском слэнге.